# Responsive Site Blank Print Preview

Tags: css, printing, responsive-design, media, preview

I've tried everything I know to get our responsive site http://www.usalight.com to print.  I've tried adding @media queries to our stylesheets like below:

```
@media print {
  * { 
    text-shadow: none !important;
    color: #000 !important; 
    background: transparent !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
  }
}
```

I've tried adding a separate print.css stylesheet linked in our header like below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/print.css" media="print">
```

I've also added `media="print,screen"` to all our stylesheets to no avail. I don't get why I can't get anything to show up in print preview.  Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to have something to do with the fact that almost all your page is inside the `.navbar-default` div. Adding ending div tag before your `#main-body` id allows most of the page to print.

Comment: My rep isn't high enough to upvote your solution, but it does work to a degree, so thank you!

Any idea why the inner template content still won't print here, for example?

http://www.usalight.com/USA-Brand-LED-10W-Smooth-A19-2700K-p/us-a19-10w-27k.htm